# trace route result same hop but different destination ip

Tags: traceroute, network-discovery

I do traceroute in my router and I found result like this

```
    traceroute to 114.0.36.130, 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
  1  114.0.17.30 (114.0.17.30)    3.49 ms  14.2 ms  2.65 ms 
  2  114.0.27.1 (114.0.27.1)    4.30 ms  3.84 ms  6.63 ms 
  3  114.0.1.213 (114.0.1.213)    9.38 ms  8.63 ms  10.2 ms 
  4  114.0.12.110 (114.0.12.110)    5.19 ms 
  4  114.0.2.38 (114.0.2.38)    4.49 ms 
  4  114.0.12.110 (114.0.12.110)    4.68 ms
  5  114.0.34.33 (114.0.34.33)    4.58 ms  4.77 ms
  5  114.0.33.194 (114.0.33.194)    6.41 ms 
  6  114.0.32.130 (114.0.32.130)    4.82 ms 
  6  114.0.34.14 (114.0.34.14)    4.83 ms 
  6  114.0.33.198 (114.0.33.198)    6.56 ms 
  7  114.0.36.130 (114.0.36.130)    6.74 ms  17.0 ms  6.09 ms
```

From the result, I found there is some hop is same but destination ip is different. Could you help me to know about this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that result on a trace is that, some ISP, does load balance in his Autonomus System, thats it: same destination across diferent ways.

This is the reason that you looks, in the same hop, ex: 4, 5 and 6, that one packet goes hrough every one of the links that can reach the destination.

Comment: Is it similar with when activate ecmp in internal network isn't it?

Comment: On an internal network: If you refer into a LAN, this will not happend because on a LAN, all IPs share the same broadcast domain, all have the same ip address range. If you refer into a internal network divided with routers, with different networks inside(diferents LANs), if you activate load balance in some way, and, on dependency of your network size,  you can see also your output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "some hop is same but destination ip is different"? The destination IP in your case is `114.0.36.130`, and this is the last hop.

On different runs of traceroute to a destination, you can certainly see different paths to that destination.

And, the following behavior is common - multiple routers replying to the same probe TTL packet. This usually is the case when the routers belong to the same ISP. Why they do it? My guess is that the ISP does this for load balancing etc, as Orlando pointed out, or perhaps sometimes due to a poorly configured network!

Comment: I am sorry, I think misunderstanding. I mean same hop but different ip path? is it correct.  or how to say that

Comment: I guess what you mean is "same hop, but multiple replies". In any case, that has been explained in the answers given.

Comment: @AbhishekBalajiR first, if you don't understand the question, you should have commented on the question, instead of writing a mostly 'guessed' answer. Second, it does not matter what you guess- if you don't know the what actually the answer is, you should not answered in the first place.